# Audio record using WebAudio api in react with play/pause feature

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-audio-api

I have an application in react with webaudio api, for recording voice . It has play/pause feature.
Some times audio is playing with out voice , sometimes some parts are missing but audio length is correct. Some times audio is correct. Below is my code. Can anybody point out the mistake in the code?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css';


var audioBufferUtils = require("audio-buffer-utils")
var encodeWAV = require('audiobuffer-to-wav')

let audio = new Audio();
var context = new AudioContext()
var audioBuffer = []
function App() {

  var status  = true

  function listen() {
    initDevice()
  }

  function pauseRecording(){
    if (status){
      context.suspend()
      status = false
    }
    else{
      context.resume()
      status = true
    }
    
  }

  function initDevice(){
  const handleSuccess = function(stream) {
    const source = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    const processor = context.createScriptProcessor(1024, 1, 1);
    
    source.connect(processor);
    processor.connect(context.destination);
    processor.onaudioprocess = function(e) {
      audioBuffer =  audioBufferUtils.concat(audioBuffer,e.inputBuffer)
    };
  };

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false })
      .then(handleSuccess);
  };
  function saveAudio(){
    context.suspend()
    var wav = encodeWAV(audioBuffer)
    var blob = new Blob([ new DataView(wav) ], {
      type: 'audio/wav'
    })

    let finalAudio = new Audio()
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)        
    finalAudio.src = url
    finalAudio.play()
    saveAs(blob,"test.wav")

  }

  return (
        <div >
          <Button variant="warning" id="listen" onClick={listen}>Listen</Button>
          <Button variant="warning" id="stop" onClick={pauseRecording}>play/pause</Button>

          <Button variant="warning" id="stop" onClick={saveAudio}>Save</Button>
        </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I want to use webaudio api, because I have to process the audio once recording finished

Answer (score 0):

The code seems fine. I suspect the issue here is the `ScriptProcessor` is choking. As in it can't finish executing `onaudioprocess` in time for the next call to `onaudioprocess`. That usually results in this kind of random behaviour.

A simple thing to try is to play with the ScriptProcessor's `bufferSize` parameter. Increasing that might help sometimes.

Another possible solution could be to move the concatenation of the AudioBuffers to a WebWorker that way the main thread is ready to execute the next  `onaudioprocess`. I believe libraries like recorder.js do that.

Finally, you can also consider using something like https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs or one of it's updated forks to do this